# SSRS passing hidden parameter from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have a report that deals with presenting a table with data, I use the MvcReportViewerFluent to view the report on the page.

```
@(Html.MvcReportViewerFluent(Model.ReportPath)
.ReportParameters(Model.ReportParameter)
.Attributes(new { Height = 900, Width = "100%", style = "border: none" })
.ControlSettings(new ControlSettings() {ShowExportControls=true, AsyncRendering=true, ShowReportBody=true })
)
```

In the report there is a link that is built with the concatenation of various parameters including the baseUrl parameter of the hidden type, for a couple of days this parameter seems as if it were not populated but took its default value.
To populate this parameter I use the ReportParameters property to which I pass a dictionary with the parameter.

```
model.ReportParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>();
model.ReportParameter.Add("BaseUrl", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlBase"].ToString());
```

Note that in addition to this parameter, other parameters that work perfectly are presented on the screen.

I also tried to make this parameter visible and I saw that it is not even populated, the strange fact is that in the test environment it gave the same problem which then solved itself without making any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a cache problem that remained hanging on the server after some changes were made to the report itself, for some reason the parameters were not updated, the solution was to delete the report and reload it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you meant by "the baseUrl parameter of the hidden type". In order to pass hidden parameters to ssrs you just append it to a query string like so:

[BaseurlofSSRS]?[myhiddenparamname]=[value]

This should work.